# Store Static files on S3 _AND_ locally at the same time?

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I've successfully used `django-storages` to store all my static and media files in Django on Amazon S3 - however I also want to store them on the server as well at the same time.

So, when I run `collectstatic` I want it to both sync the `/static` folder and the `s3.domain.tld/static` folder.

My settings looks like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cupcard/static')]
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = "http://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'lindshop.utils.custom_storages.CachedS3BotoStorage'
```

My current Static Storage looks like this:

```
class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def save(self, name, content):
        non_gzipped_file_content = content.file
        name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
        content.file = non_gzipped_file_content
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        return name
```

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic` it only syncs with the S3. It does not add the files to the local `/static` folder.